# Парить, реять, витать низко, под одеялом

Tags: грамотная-речь

Могут ли слова "парить", "реять", "витать" означать мельтешение, движение, пребывание в воздухе, но в ограниченном пространстве? Например под одеялом (о мечтах перед сном, о лепестках: описывая ощущение приятной истомы). Все эти слова подразумевают высокую даль?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой После "лепестках" нельзя двоеточие. Как вы пропустили?))))) Да и "например" вводное - запятая всё-таки была правильной.

Comment: @oleedd: нет, если "например" идёт и сам пример, запятой выделяется весь оборот. То, что было в скобках, я вообще не читал. :)

Comment: Двоеточие - раскрываются подробности. О лепестках (что ииенно, в каком случае?) : описывая ощущение приятной истомы.

Answer (score 1):

Главное условие для этих слов - находится над поверхностью, не касаясь её. Если для лепестков под одеялом достаточно места, чтобы не лежать на поверхности, а быть в воздухе над ней, то тогда можно так говорить...

Answer (score 0):

Витать - это и есть основное значение слова (словарь Ушакова) - высокий полёт фантазий - предаваться бесплодным мечтам, забывать о действительности.

Парить - перен. возноситься в область возвышенных идей, мыслей, мечтать, предаваться фантазиям.

А вот у "реять" такого переносного значения нет.

"Высокая даль" как раз подразумевается именно в переносном смысле. (Птицы парят/реют в воздухе на любой высоте.)

А место совсем роли не играет - что под одеялом, что сидя в автобусе, что сидя за партой.

Comment: В той метафоре, о которой речь, имеется все же некий буквализм. Реют, витают, парят лепестки под одеялом. Реют, витают, парят мечты под одеялом. Внутри метафоры, но буквально. То есть речь идет о выражении в переносном значении, в котором эти слова употребляются в прямом значении.

Comment: Есть и такое в словаре: парить - держаться в воздухе на неподвижно распростертых крыльях; лететь или просто держаться в воздухе. То есть движение не обязательно и можно парить на одном месте. Главное условие для этих слов: **быть над поверхностью, не касаться её**. Ещё важный момент. Если лепестки не настоящие, то никакое одеяло их сдерживать не будет. Они будут просто вокруг в чьём-то представлении.